# Как выбрать число выполненного условия

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Допустим у меня есть код `if a or b:` и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если выполнялось первое условие (а), то `с = 0`, а если второе условие (b), то `с = 1`, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: `if a: c = 0`, `if b: c = 1`.

Comment: А если оба условия выполняются или не выполняются?, что `с=?`

Comment: Если в том случае, когда оба значения ложные, `с` просто не меняется, то случай одновременной истинности создает явную неопределенность и результат будет кардинально отличаться в зависимости от того, в какой очередности программист поставит проверку `a` и `b`.
Поэтому для достижения детерминированного результата нужно либо строго задать очередность проверок `a` и `b` либо доопределить таблицу истинности для случая, когда `a` и `b` одновременно истинны.

Comment: @Oopss, как задан вопрос, так написан комментарий. На выбор: программисту безразлично что будет в других ситуациях или программист гарантирует что других ситуаций нет или программист забыл про другие ситуации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть множество вариантов записать это.

```py
# Первый вариант
if a:
    c = 0
elif b:
    c = 1

# Второй вариант
if a or b:
    c = 0 if a else 1

# Третий вариант
if a or b:
    if a:
        c = 0
    else:
        c = 1

# Четвертый вариант (Внутри функции)
if a or b:
    if a:
        return a
    return b

# Пятый вариант (Синтаксис: True if условие else False )
c = (0 if a else 1) if a or b else 0


# Шестой вариант (Синтаксис: (False,True)[условие] )
c = (0,1)[(a,b)[a or b]]
```

Последние варианты как самые быстрые и стабильные, но написаны под разные ответы при одинаковых условиях

```
# Пятый вариант
0 - True и False
1 - False и True
0 - False и False
0 - True и True

# Шестой вариант
0 - True и False
1 - False и True
0 - False и False
1 - True и True
```

Comment: `return a`, `return b` ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если это как def, то можно при передаче параметров a и b вернуть нужную переменную. Хотя да, можно просто сразу же return 0 и return 1

Comment: Переменные не возвращаются, возвращаются значения. Весь код можно заменить на `return True`.

Answer (score 2):

Невозможно определить, если правдивым было `a` или `b` (или оба `a` и `b`), зная только то, что `a or b` правдиво.

Нужно дальше тестировать, например на правдивость  `a`:

```
if a or b:
    c = 0 if a else 1
```

или с тем же самым результатом, но не так компактно

```
if a or b:
    if a:
        c = 0
    else:
        c = 1
```

Или возможно целиком пропустить тест на `a or b`:

```
if a:
    c = 0
if b:
    c = 1
```